# Mathtools: Automatic italic corrections before math not working when combined with ~

Tags: mathtools, italic-correction

In `mathtools`, I've noticed that the automatic italic correction before math doesn't work when combined with `~`. For instance, in

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}\itshape
Compare these lines: \par
\mathtoolsset{mathic} % or \mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
Subset of \(V\) and subset of \(A\). \par
Subset of~\(V\) and subset of~\(A\). \par
\mathtoolsset{mathic=false}
Subset of \(V\) and subset of \(A\).
\par
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

you can see that the line with the `~`'s has no italic corrections before the math italic letters:

[image: A snapshot of the result]

I emailed the `mathtools` team about this, and they said they'd put it on their to-do list, but in the meantime I thought I'd see if anyone here knows to fix it. Maybe the redefinition of `\(` in `mathtools` needs to use `\sw@slant`?

Comment: i find the phrasing of this question a bit confusing.  italic corrections operate *after* an italic letter, not before, so the italic corrections here are not *in* math, but in the (italic) text preceding the math.  after reading the documentation in the `mathtools` manual, i guess what i'm really objecting to is the name of the key, but it's too late to do anything about that.  however, perhaps the title of the question could be rephrased to avoid an erroneous interpretation.  (i'll think about how this might be done.)

Comment: Okay, now I'm talking about the italic corrections "before math".

Comment: From my research it comes down to `\skip@\lastskip\unskip\@italiccorr\hskip\skip@`, so my guess is that `\@italiccorr` ends up with nothing because of the `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a chat with someone more knowledgeable than me, we come to the following conclusion: *this is tricky in general*.

Here is the problem. Italic correction can only be added after a character or ligature (see TeX by Topic, edition from 2007, CTAN, section 4.3.3). But `~` contains a penalty which effectively kill of the italic correction, so the `\@italiccorr` that the `mathic` option inserts will be zero.

You can easily see the effect via

```
\itshape
f V

f\/ V

f\penalty0\/ V
```

[image]

I'll add a remark in the manual.

---

EDIT: Since we know what `~` does, we can get around this particular problem.

`~` does a penalty plus a space, so carefully added storing of lastskip and lastpenalty plus some unskip and unpenalty will do the trick.